# How to solve this cipher?

Tags: cipher

I'm given the cipher ESELUBRKXDBWTHARE and am told that it's a J. Bond quote.    The only cryptography techniques I know are caesar ciphers and substitution ciphers. I learnt the vignere cipher after encountering this problem but am stuck as I do not know the key word.

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: It appears that you got this cipher from somewhere else. Could you edit your question to give credit to the source? Also, as an FYI, the ciphertext is likely too short to be satisfactorily solved.

Comment: @Brandon_J  and Rubio The OP writes "I'm given the cipher" not "I found this cipher somewhere". Does adding "... by a friend" solve your problem with this?

Comment: @Rubio I think that would be your call.

Comment: I actually didn't notice @Bananenkopp has almost certainly solved it, or I probably would have just let this slide. This is a case where some additional context may well have proven necessary to give would-be solvers a loose end to tug at—but in this case it seems there was enough here to go on after all.  All that said, we do want posters to cite where things came from, to the best of their knowledge; if this actually came from "a friend" and they can't be more specific, then we usually accept that.

Comment: I have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, try different ciphers, different solvers, different passwords.

You mentioned vignere, but dont know a key. Lets try

> Vignere as the Cipher and BOND as the key

That gives us

> DERITNEHWPOTSTNOD

And the answer is:

> DERITNEHWPOTSTNOD reversed gives: **Don't stop when tired.**